# Moving quadwords to xmm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, sse

I just want to know the code to use to move a 64-bit register with number in it to a xmm register. My thought was:

```
`movsd xmm1, [r14]`
```

But I keep getting a `segmentation fault: 11`.

I am using NASM x86 on Mac OS-X.

Someone please help.

Comment: Don't you mean `movsd xmm1, r14`?

Comment: I just tried that and I'm still getting a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`movsd xmm1, [r14]` attempts to load a double from the *address* stored in `r14`.  That's not what you want.  Instead, use:

```
movq xmm1, r14
```

Comment: Im still getting a segmentation fault

Comment: @GolfinGamer: that instruction can't segfault, because there is no memory access.  Either you typed it wrong, or your bug is somewhere else.  Note that it is `r14`, *not* `[r14]`.

Comment: I got the segfault to stop but my program is still not working. I don't think the value of r14 is getting the correct value. But thanks for the help. This is the correct line of code I needed

Comment: I'm still actually having trouble grabbing the number from r14. I have tested it and found that r14 does have then number but when i check to see if it is in xmm1 after using this line of code, it is not in xmm1. what am I doing wrong?